# Distribution of normal variable subtracted from another normal random variable?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

$$X\sim N(a,c^2), \text{ }\text{ } \text{ }\text{ }Y\sim N(b,d^2)$$

Then $$X+Y \sim N(a+b,c^2+d^2)$$

**What is the distribution of $X-Y$?**

I can't figure out if it is
$$N(a-b,c^2-d^2)$$ or  $$N(a-b,c^2+d^2)$$

Comment: Would your first guess make sense when $d^2$ exceeds $c^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your notation, the distribution will be $N(a-b,c^2+d^2)$:
$$X-Y \sim N(a-b,c^2+d^2)$$

Here is a detailed explanation that should help:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html

Answer (score 5):

Its is correct as stated in the previous answer that the difference of two *independent* normal random variables $X\sim N(a,c^2)$ and $X\sim N(b,d^2)$ is distributed as 
\begin{equation}
X-Y \sim N(a-b,c^2 + d^2)
\end{equation}
This intuition follows naturally from the additive property of the expected value $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$ and that the variance of the difference between two random variables are given by 
\begin{equation}
Var(X-Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2Cov(X,Y)
\end{equation}
with $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ for two independent variables. This also imply that the formula presented in the other answer is not correct when the variables are *correlated*. Then, 
\begin{equation}
X-Y \sim N(a-b,c^2 + d^2-2\rho_{x,y} c\cdot d)
\end{equation}
where $\rho_{x,y}$ is the correlation between the two random variables.